# How to connect bot to communication application?

Tags: botframework, bots, circuit-sdk

Is it possible to connect bot created using Microsoft Bot Framework on .NET Core that deployed in Azure and bot account that was created in Circuit messenger (by Unify)? And if it's possible, what should I use?

Answer (score 0):

At this time there is no special adapter available for the Circuit SDK to use the Microsoft Bot Framework. But since the Circuit SDK is a plain JavaScript SDK you should be able to use it in any framework.